# Angular: error- TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

I know many of you will say this is a duplicate question, but my concern is a little different. I want to show data of a fake API which I got from jsonplaceholder.com on my web page. I have created a service where I am using that API, Below are my files and error.

```
error- TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

api.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }
  names(): Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
}
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageserviceService } from '../services/messageservice.service';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  childdata;
  itemname;
  price:boolean=false;
  list={};
  constructor(private http:ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit():any {
    this.http.names().subscribe(data=> this.list=data)
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{list.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `list={}` <- doesn't have a `.name`, isn't a list (or array). Also you don't seem to have bothered with a type for the API response, please read https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting in the response is an array not an object, in order to display those details , you need to use [**ngFor**](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data)

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let listObj of list">
      {{ listObj?.name}}
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: The OP is reporting a *TypeScript compiler error*, which is coming well before there is a response from (or even request to) the API. The initial value of list is **not** an array, so they'll see errors if they try to `ngFor` loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `list` is an array. The data returned from jsonplaceholder, after parsed by the Angular `HttpClient` will be converted into a javascript array in need of manual traversal.

You can achieve that by changing the code in your `app.component.html` to loop over the array:

```
<ul *ngFor="let itm of list">
    <li>{{itm.name ? itm.name : ''}}</li>
</ul>
```

If you don't want to use the ternary operator, you could always use a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: Likewise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800267/angular-error-ts2339-property-name-does-not-exist-on-type#comment112819973_63800329